# implement single `numberOfRowsInSection` method for two tables in same view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a view controller with a segmented control that controls which of two `UITable`s a user sees. When you switch between indexes of the segmented control, a different fetch request is made and the table reloads data. One `UITable` (segment index 1) allows users to add and remove rows. I set the table's delegate and data source in the Storyboard and also in `viewDidLoad`.

I have realized that if I go to this view controller, switch to segment index 1 and then switch back to index 0, I get an invalid update error. I believe this is because of my implementation of numberofRowsInSection. At the moment, I evaluated the number of rows by first checking the segmented control index. However, that approach fails when I am trying to update the table in seg index 1, but I exited the view controller on seg index 0.

How can I figure out what is calling numberOfRowsInSection so that I can evaluate the number of rows regardless of the segmented control's current index?

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.34.4/UITableView.m:2011
>               Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
>               (null)

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender {

    //first table
    if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        /*for switching between collection map view and browse list */
        _table.hidden= NO;

        [mapVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [mapVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        [_mapVC removeFromParentViewController];

        _searchController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
        if (storedDataset_ != dataset) {
            speciesCurrentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataset & %d > 0", dataset];
        }

        [self fetchResultsUsingSegmentedControlIndex];

        if (currentSelectedIndexPath)
        {
            [[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedIndexPath] setSelected:NO animated:YES];
            currentSelectedIndexPath = nil;
        }

        [_table reloadData];

        // Define your required task...
    }
    /*second "tab" - My Collection
     set up table view of user's collected leafs*/
    else if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
      //  _searchController.searchBar.hidden = YES;
        NSError *error;
        [self collectionFetchedResultsController:collectionCurrentPredicate];
        [self.collectionFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        [_table reloadData];
        collectedLeafArray = [collectionFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];

    }
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)collectionFetchedResultsController:(NSPredicate*)predicate
        {
        NSString * sectionNameKeyPath = nil;
      /*  if (collectionFetchedResultsController != nil)
        {
            return collectionFetchedResultsController;
        }*/

        NSManagedObjectContext* context = [(LeafletAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        // Create and configure a fetch request with the Species entity.
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"this a predicate %@", predicate);
        if(predicate){
            sectionNameKeyPath = @"selectedSpecies";
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        }

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CollectedLeaf" inManagedObjectContext:context] ;
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Create the sort descriptors array.
        NSSortDescriptor *idDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"collectedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:idDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
        collectionFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:nil];
        collectionFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        // Memory management.
        [fetchRequest release];
        [idDescriptor release];
        [sortDescriptors release];

        return collectionFetchedResultsController;
    }

    - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    {
        // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
        NSLog(@"begin updates called");
        [_table beginUpdates];
    }

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
           atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
          newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
        switch(type) {

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                NSLog(@"ns fetched results change insert at %@", [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]);
                [_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                NSLog(@"ns fetched results change update");
              //  [_table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                            //     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                [self configureCell:[_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }

    }

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [_table insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [_table deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                //nothing
                break;
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                //
                break;
        }
    }

    - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    {
        // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
        NSLog(@"end updates called");
        [_table endUpdates];

    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        /*Only allow deletion for collection table */
        if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
            {
                NSLog(@"index path at commitediting style %@", indexPath);
                //id  result  = nil;
                CollectedLeaf * collectedLeaf = nil;
                if ([[collectionFetchedResultsController sections] count] > [indexPath section]){
                    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[collectionFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
                    if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] > [indexPath row]){
                       collectedLeaf = [collectionFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                        LeafletPhotoUploader * leafletPhotoUploader = [[LeafletPhotoUploader alloc] init];
                        leafletPhotoUploader.collectedLeaf = collectedLeaf;

                        if([LeafletUserRegistration isUserRegistered]) {
                            [leafletPhotoUploader deleteCollectedLeaf:collectedLeaf delegate:self];
                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"I am not registered and want to delete leaf");
                        }
                        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [collectionFetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
                        [context deleteObject:collectedLeaf];

                        NSError *error;
                        if (![context save:&error])
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                            NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
                            if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0)
                            {
                                for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors)
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The object gets saved to Core Data in `PhotoUploader.m`:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    //NSLog(@"Photo uploader response: %@", responseString);
    // Use when fetching binary data
    //NSData *responseData = [request responseData];

    NSError *error;
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"Photo uploader response: %@", jsonDictionary);

    if (jsonDictionary == nil)
    {

        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kLeafletErrorDomain code:kErrorResultNotReady userInfo:nil];
        if(![self isALabelRequest:request] && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletPhotoUploader:didFailWithError:)])
        {
            [delegate leafletPhotoUploader:self didFailWithError:error];
        }
    }

    else if (collectedLeaf)
    {
        // If this is the first time uploading
        if(collectedLeaf.leafID == nil) {
            NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(LeafletAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

            collectedLeaf.leafID = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];

            LeafletURL* segmentedImageURL = (LeafletURL*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LeafletURL" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
            segmentedImageURL.dataSource = @"SegmentedImage";
            segmentedImageURL.type = @"SegmentedImage";
            segmentedImageURL.rawURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/segmented.png", collectedLeaf.leafID];
            segmentedImageURL.hiResImageLocation = kLocationServer;
            segmentedImageURL.thumbnailLocation = kLocationServer;
            collectedLeaf.segmentedImageURL = segmentedImageURL;

            LeafletURL* originalImageURL = (LeafletURL*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LeafletURL" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
            originalImageURL.dataSource = @"OriginalImage";
            originalImageURL.type = @"OriginalImage";
            originalImageURL.rawURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/original.jpg", collectedLeaf.leafID];
            originalImageURL.hiResImageLocation = kLocationServer;
            originalImageURL.thumbnailLocation = kLocationServer;
            collectedLeaf.originalImageURL = originalImageURL;

            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL success = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
            if(!success){
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error saving %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                [self showAlert];
            }else{
                /*If successfully saved uploaded leaf, delete image stored in documents directory from collecting w/o internet connection */
                if(collectedLeaf.localImageFileName){
                    [self removeImage:collectedLeaf.localImageFileName];
                }
            }
        } else {
            // This means that the labeling has changed
            NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(LeafletAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
            collectedLeaf.syncStatus = kSyncStatusSame;
            [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        }
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    if(![self isALabelRequest:request] && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletPhotoUploader:didUploadImage:)])
    {
        [delegate leafletPhotoUploader:self didUploadImage:collectedLeaf];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title seems wrong?

Comment: @Koen this better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow the chain of events exactly, but that error message is a sign of a common error. What it means is that the table view data source must be in sync with any insert or delete operations you perform on the table. If you tell the table view to insert a row, your data source must show that the table view has one more row than it used to have. The table view will call `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` to find out. So:

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Before your update, the table had one row. Then you told the table view to insert a row. But after that update, the table view data source still said there was one row in the table. If you start with one row and tell the table view to insert a row, the data source must now show that there are two rows.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think you're right - its an issue of my numberOfRowsInSection. I updated my post

Comment: Your question is confusing now. The table view calls the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. That's the problem, it's calling that method and you're returning an incorrect result.

Comment: Yes thats exaclty my problem. I changed the title of my question and most of the content. I am trying to figure out the caller of numberOfRowsInSection, so that I can return the correct result regardless of the segmented control's current index.

Comment: Please let me know if there is more I should change to better communicate my problem.

Comment: What do you mean, that's your problem? The table view calls that method. That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The problem is that if the numberOfRowsSection is called after updating one of the NSFetchedResultsControllers. If, in another part of the app, I update the NSFetchedResultsController associated with seg control index 1, but the index is still set to 0, numberOfRows will return the number of rows for the NSFetchedResultsController associated with seg 0